# Dynamically Currency in UITextField - Swift 3

Tags: swift, xcode, formatter

I have this piece of code, from GitHub and some StackOverflow posts

```
extension String {

    // formatting text for currency textField
    func currencyInputFormatting() -> String {

        var number: NSNumber!
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .currencyAccounting
        formatter.currencySymbol = "$"
        formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
        formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2

        var amountWithPrefix = self

        // remove from String: "$", ".", ","
        let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "[^0-9]", options: .caseInsensitive)
        amountWithPrefix = regex.stringByReplacingMatches(in: amountWithPrefix, options: NSRegularExpression.MatchingOptions(rawValue: 0), range: NSMakeRange(0, self.characters.count), withTemplate: "")

        let double = (amountWithPrefix as NSString).doubleValue
        number = NSNumber(value: (double / 100))

        // if first number is 0 or all numbers were deleted
        guard number != 0 as NSNumber else {
            return ""
        }

        return formatter.string(from: number)!
    }
}
```

I use this extension to be able to dynamically create currency format in UI text field when the user types in.
It is working fine but, I am not able to delete what I've written.
I have to drag the cursor manually to the position of what I want to delete otherwise it won't work. 
Why is that happening

Comment: So this is just a string extension code that do the conversion. The delete problem is caused by the way you use it I think. Do you have a text change listener in your text field and call this method and then set text? Or how do you use this code exactly?

Comment: I use a 
func myTextFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) { 
        if let amountString = textField.text?.currencyInputFormatting() {
            textField.text = amountString
        }
}

exactly like the example on GitHub, then I add a target to the textField with this function for the event ".editingChanged"

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to add listener in this way

```
textfield.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: .editingChanged)
```

And run your function in this way

```
func textFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) {
    let cur = textField.text!.currencyInputFormatting()
    textField.text = cur
}
```

Everything works fine. I can delete my input from the end and the formatting still kicks in as long as I have a number there. So after a set text action on a textField, the cursor will be automatically moved to the end of the string so you can only delete characters from the end. If you want to delete any other characters, just drag the cursor like when you are editing texts in your notebook.

Comment: I see on the simulator it works but not on my iPhone.

Comment: @Glatteisen That's wired. What happened on your iPhone? The cursor disappeared or anything?

Comment: In the simulator, it looks like this and it works $2,131,231.23|

On my iPhone, it looks like this 2.131.231,23 $|

Comment: Maybe it is because I am in Germany? So because of my location, the formatter adapts to German currency spelling?
In Germany, we write the currency symbol at the end of the number rather than at the beginning

Comment: @Glatteisen Yes. If so, that explains. So when you delete from the end, you deleted the $ mark and then your method add that mark back and set text again. That's why you cannot delete text. So the options we have are 1. Put $ as a label and never change that. 2. If you are sure that the $ will always be in the end, after setting text, we can set cursor location.

Comment: So, I tried it with a label. I think this is a good idea but it doesn't match with the number when the user types a large number in. So I think to handle that problem I maybe would have to handle some constraints for the label to the text?

So, I tried it with setting the cursor location and now it works.


Thank you